# Using Rolle's Theorem to Prove the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem

Tags: functions, derivatives, rolles-theorem

Sorry for the broad title. The question is too long to fit in the title.

Here is the question:

> Let $\space f,g: \space [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \space$ be differentiable functions with $\space g'(x) \neq 0 \space$ for all $\space x\in (a,b).$
>
> Suppose we define the following function:
>
> $$h: \space [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
>
> With $\space h(x)=f(x)-kg(x)$.
>
> Using Rolle's theorem for **a suitable choice of $\space k \space$**; prove that there exists a real number $\space c\in (a,b) \space$ such that:
>
> $${f'(c)\over g'(c)} = {{f(b)-f(a)}\over {g(b)-g(a)}}$$

I gave it a try, but not sure if I'm right.

Here is what I did:

> For Rolle's Theorem to  be applied, we require $\space h(a)=h(b) \space $. In other words:
>
> $$f(a)-kg(a) = f(b)-kg(b)$$
>
> By rearranging, we get:
>
> $$f(a)-f(b) = kg(a)-kg(b)$$
>
> $$f(a)-f(b) = k \big(g(a)-g(b) \big)$$
>
> $${{f(a)-f(b)}\over {g(a)-g(b)}} = {{f(b)-f(a)}\over {g(b)-g(a)}} = k$$
>
> Which gives us the equality:
>
> $${f'(c)\over g'(c)} = k$$

Here is where I get confused. Is this what it's asking me to do?

Or have I dived into the uncharted and gone in the completely wrong direction (won't be my first time haha).

Comment: Almost. Once you compute $k$ in terms of $f(a),f(b),g(a),g(b)$, then you can apply Rolle's theorem to $h(x)$. Apply it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $h(x)=f(x)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}g(x)$. Then $h(b)=h(a)$ and so $h'(c)=0$ for some $c\in(a,b)$. But$$h'(c)=0\Longleftrightarrow\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}.$$

Comment: I am not sure if this is necessary, but you also have that $g(b) \neq g(a)$ by the condition that $g'(x)$ is never zero on $(a,b)$ (follows from Rolle's theorem), hence the constant $k$ is well defined.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary.

Comment: I meant necessary as in 'necessary to mention it explicitly' :)

Comment: Yes, it is. I should have done it.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. This is from the fact that $f'(c) = {{f(b) - f(a)}\over b-a}$ for some $c\in (a,b)$ and the same can be said for $g'(c)$ right? Sorry for bombarding you with questions haha. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @MaxEchendu No, that's not it. $h'(c)=0\Longleftrightarrow f'(c)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}g'(c)=0\Longleftrightarrow\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - Ahhhhh that makes A LOT of sense. Thank you so much. I appreciate it.