# Using the Rolle's method to prove function property

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

We had the following statement given to us, that, there are two functions $h$ and $j$, where $h,j : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. And these functions are continuous and differentiable on this interval too. Now, what we have to prove is the following: $\frac{j(b)-j(a)}{h(b)-h(a)} = \frac{j^{'}(c)}{h'(c)}$. I am a little confused about how to do this question. I saw this post here:

[Using Rolle's Theorem to Prove the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335048/using-rolles-theorem-to-prove-the-cauchy-mean-value-theorem).

But I do not know how to approach the question above.

Comment: Hint: recall the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ is defined as $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$. Now apply this definition to RHS (and prove it's well defined and equal to LHS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly we assume that $h' \ne 0$ on $(a,b)$, $h,j$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and $h,j$ have derivatives on $(a,b)$.

Now let's consider function $F(x)=h(x)-\lambda j(x)$, where $\lambda =\frac{j(b)-j(a)}{h(b)-h(a)}$. For $F$ holds Rolle's theorem, so $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $F'(c)=0$. It's easy to show, that $\lambda =\frac{j'(c)}{h'(c)}$.